# Listing rank of prizes on CV

Tags: cv, awards

If I won 3rd place or an honorable mention for Award X. Is it reasonable to simply state the name of the award without stating what place I got?

Comment: The placement is usually part of the award. Nominations, for example. It'd be misleading to write *Nobel Prize for Economics* when you were a nominee but not the actual winner, as an example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not think it is reasonable. If you are mentioning you won at a competition, you must also mention what was your place or in what capacity you won an award. There are good reasons for this in my opinion. First, it is possible the reader is aware of the competition and finds it misleading of you. Second, if you clearly mention the details of the award, it is possible you might rise in the eyes of reader for your integrity and honesty.

Answer (score 6):

Mentioning an award without the rank implies that there was only once recipient. You need to mention the ranking if it's actually rank-based, especially if you didn't finish first.